# How can we programmatically generate MS Teams Code

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, pnp-js

In MS Teams we can manually generate Teams Code and Teams Link which can be used by others to join that Team. Is it possible to programmatically generate this code or link?

Any options in PnP (PowerShell or CSOM or JS) or MS graph API?

Check this link to see the manual way of generating Team link and Team code - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-link-or-a-code-for-joining-a-team-11b0de3b-9288-4cb4-bc49-795e7028296f?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can create the link to a team programmatically.

Team URL structure : `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/team/<channelId>/conversations?groupId=<groupId>&tenantId=<tenantId>`

You can get channel Id,group Id and tenant Id in 2 ways.

1. From Bot context in code
2. Using graph API for [joinedTeams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and [List Channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Thanks Subhashish.. I'll give it a try and will let you know.. Thanks a lot